# Linking to select list boxes together PHP HTML Website Work

Tags: php, html, web

I am required to build a website with a makeshift Cart... I have a select box that shows a product name and 1 box that i want to show the product price (all he information is stored on myPHP)

Is there a way to link/connect the 2 boxes together, so when a user selects the product, the other box will populate with the price? All i can get at the moment is all of the information into the select box....this is doing my tree in.

[image: The layout at the moment (I know it says qty not price... its in testing)]

As you can see the price is in the drop down box but i want it to populate in the box below.

Any help would be appreciated.

the code i am using at the moment is...

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM tblproducts";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo "<select name='product'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['productName'] . "'>" . $row['productName'] . " £" .         $row['productPrice'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

I know i have selected all with dropdown box... and there is nothing that points to the empty text box.. this is because I am unsure how to link / point to it.

Comment: You need some javascript to do that.

Comment: Do note that the use of the mysql functions are deprecated. You may wish to read into "PDO" or check PHP's own guide to help you choose which set you wish to use. (Which would be there -> http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: yeah, you'll need javascript/ jquery/ any other framework to do that. The reason is that PHP is executed before the page is loaded so once you see it you can't do anything again with PHP on the page unless you used any of the above with AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using an `ajax` call:

call a function or file on `onchange` event of first dropdown. pass the selected value value of first dropdown to that function or file

then in that function or file select options based on that value, and on success populate those options in second dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by loading prices to a `javascript`. Use `onchange` event for first block and populate the price of another.